# React Native: Resize an image and put it in the top of the screen

Tags: css, react-native, image-resizing, css-content

I want to resize the image to fit my desired width and height and put it in the top. This is my code:

```
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Image source={TOP_START_GRAPHIC} style={styles.topStartImage} />
      // another contents goes here...
    </View>
```

style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  topStartImage: {
    resizeMode: "contain",
    width: screen.width * 0.6,
    height: screen.height * 0.4,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
})
```

this is the result:
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/790ZB.png)

I found out that it happens because I set the `resizeMode: "contain"` so that it puts the mage in the center. But if I dont set it, the image will be cropped and super zoom like this:
[if I don't resize the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E33fY.png)

I expect it to be in the top of the screen with the image fully shown like the first image. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image inside a **View** like this ,

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View style={styles.topStartContainer}>
    <Image source={TOP_START_GRAPHIC} style={styles.topStartImage} resizeMode="contain" />
  </View>
  {/* Other contents go here */}
</View>
```

After that give styling for this container as ,

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  topStartContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 20, // Adjust this value as needed to set the desired spacing
  },
  topStartImage: {
    width: '60%',
    aspectRatio: 1, // Maintain the original aspect ratio of the image
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
});
```

This can hold your image in your  desired location (In your case center).

Comment: hi! Thanks for giving it a shot, I appreciate the effort! But I still got the whitespace above the image as when I set the resizeMode to contain, it will make the image in the center of the space. I want to put the image in the top of the space.

Comment: Hii. Can you share your project in the snack and give the snack link here . It would be much appreciated.